# How do I merge two UV map islands into one without losing faces

Tags: uv

Look at the selected faces in the below UV map. Clearly it's one continuous face of the object, and I'd like to texture it as such, but the UV map splits it into 4 separate islands.

[image]

How can I tell the UV map tool to keep those faces together as a single island?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. For future askers, select the mutual edge you want to join on, and then use "Stitch" or alt+V to merge them.